# How to Pass an index / value to different cards in react. Only last item appears

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, e-commerce

In Short, Let's assume that I have a list of items that I am displaying, and on each item there is a button, like a Quick View button to view extra information about the product in a modal pop-up. Now, everything is working perfectly, except when **I click on the button, it brings the information related to the last item of my API/JSON file** .. whatever the source of the file is. So, the **last item in the Array**. when I `console.log(index)`
it brings the correct index for each card, but it doesn't show the information about each product separately.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { productsInfo } from "./ProductsData";  //  the JS file containing the data
import Modal from "react-modal";
import "./Products.css";
import ProductDetailsPopUp from "./ProductDetailsPopUp";
import axios from "axios";

Modal.setAppElement("#root");
export default class Products extends Component {
  state = {
    productsData: [],
    modalIsOpen: false,
  };
  
  OpenModal = () => {
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: true });
  };
  CloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: false });
  };
  changeProduct = (item, index) => {
    this.setState({ showProduct: item });
  };
  render() {
    // const {id, img, title, price, isNew, country, currency} = productsInfo

    return (
      <div className="ProductsContainer">
        {productsInfo.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="cardHolder" key={item.id}>
              <img src={item.img} alt="Products" />
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  this.OpenModal();
                  console.log(index);
                }}
                className="MainProductBtn"
              >
                QUICK VIEW
              </button>
              <Modal
                key={index}
                className="mainModal"
                style={{
                  overlay: {
                    backgroundColor: "#3333",
                    opacity: 0.4,
                    transition: "0.4s",
                  },
                }}
                isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
                onRequestClose={this.CloseModal}
              >
                <div className="popupHeader" key={item.id}>
                  <h3>{item.title}</h3>
                  <button onClick={this.CloseModal}>×</button>
                </div>
                <ProductDetailsPopUp />
              </Modal>
              <p>{item.title}</p>
              <small>{`${item.price} USD`}</small>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried including the index in onClick function and also passing it in the state, didn't  work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create `Modal` for every item inside your `map` method meaning that it will display `productsInfo.length` modals and the last one will be on top.

Remote `Modal` tag from the `map` method and `onClick` set the current item at your state, change the display of the dialog to `true` and read the current item from the state inside your `Modal`.

e.g.

```
  state = {
    productsData: [],
    modalIsOpen: false,
    currentItem: null
  };

  OpenModal = item => {
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: true, currentItem: item });
  };

            onClick={() => {
              this.OpenModal(item);
              console.log(index);
            }}
```

Comment: Bud, I can't vote to give u a plus one, your solution saved me !! Thanks a lot ! 
So, What I was missing is a parameter (item) in my openModal function. Thanks

Comment: Also, I have a new problem where texts are now overlapping each other. Any ideas ?

Comment: For the other problem maybe you can add a code sandbox to help us better understand